How to make this Zig-Zag Progress design in Flutter?
I have the following design in Figma that I want to implement in Flutter. The design is a Zig-Zag pattern that represents a progress indicator, where it moves towards the end. When a step is completed, a custom checkmark will appear on it, marking it as done. Here is the design:

I tried using the Paint class in Flutter, but it didn’t give me the desired result.

I have not coded it yet, I tried but it was very difficult for me.

If the data is static, then just extract this as svg or png and use it in flutter app

I have tried zig-zag design with my logic check if that will meet your requirement
           Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 80,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 80,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(50)),
                            color: Colors.orange),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(0, -10),
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                      width: 120,
                      height: 10,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topRight: Radius.circular(0),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(0)),
                          color: Colors.orange),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(0, -20),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 80,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.orange),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 90,
                            height: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 80,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Transform.translate(
                        offset: Offset(0, -30),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 80,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(50)),
                              color: Colors.orange),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(0, -40),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 80,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.orange),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 90,
                            height: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 80,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Transform.translate(
                        offset: Offset(0, -50),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 80,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(50)),
                              color: Colors.orange),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(0, -60),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 80,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.orange),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 90,
                            height: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )


Bro it working fine, but I need it as dynamic. It length should be of the List length.
Anyway, thank you for a such a nice help.

I haven't really put much work into this, it's far from perfrect, but I hope that this helps. And warning, this code isn't 'clean' and 'efficient' yet:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: "Wavy UI",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WavyUI(),
    );
  }
}

class WavyUI extends StatelessWidget {
  const WavyUI({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double rangePerItem = 90;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: rangePerItem * 0),
            child: WavyItem(
              text: "Wavy 01",
              wavyDirection: AxisDirection.right,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: rangePerItem * 1),
            child: WavyItem(
              text: "Wavy 02",
              wavyDirection: AxisDirection.left,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: rangePerItem * 2),
            child: WavyItem(
              text: "Wavy 03",
              wavyDirection: AxisDirection.right,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: rangePerItem * 3),
            child: WavyItem(
              text: "Wavy 04",
              wavyDirection: AxisDirection.left,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WavyItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const WavyItem({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.wavyDirection,
  });

  final String text;
  final AxisDirection wavyDirection;

  BorderRadius _getBorderRadius(double circularRadius) {
    if (wavyDirection == AxisDirection.left) {
      return BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(circularRadius),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(circularRadius),
      );
      //
    } else {
      return BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(circularRadius),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(circularRadius),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Widget textWidget = Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
      ),
    );

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        (wavyDirection == AxisDirection.right) ? textWidget : const SizedBox.shrink(),
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 110, 150, 220),
            borderRadius: _getBorderRadius(60),
          ),
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 80,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              right: (wavyDirection == AxisDirection.right) ? 10 : 0,
              left: (wavyDirection == AxisDirection.right) ? 0 : 10,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              borderRadius: _getBorderRadius(60),
            ),
            child: const Icon(Icons.balance_outlined, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        (wavyDirection == AxisDirection.left) ? textWidget : const SizedBox.shrink(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Thus, the result:

Tweak it a little bit and you'll achieve the desired UI. Cheers.

Bro it working fine, but I need it as dynamic. It length should be of the List length.
Anyway, thank you for a such a nice help.

Bro, all you need to do is do a for loop :), e.g for (var listItem in list){ //do code}. That's it.
